# Interpretation of Feynman propagator for massive scalar field in position space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, causality, propagator

I've always treated propagator in the momentum representation so when it diverges, we are on-shell. But what is the interpretation of light-cone divergences in position space? If it is something we have to renormalize, how can I do it? More precisely, if I have to renormalize light-cone divergences of the following Feynman propagator:
\begin{equation*}
G(s)=\frac{m}{8\pi s} H^{(1)}_1(m s)\,\,,\,\,s^2=(x^0-y^0)^2-|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^2
\end{equation*}
(where $H^{(1)}_1$ is a Hankel function of the first type) how should I proceed? Is there a method like dimensional regularization for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to renormalize here.

The interpretation is that a quantum field is not an operator-valued function $\hat{\phi}(x)$, but an operator-valued distribution, aka generalized function. That means that $\hat{\phi}$ is a linear functional from test functions on space-time (e.g. you can choose functions with compact support to get temporal distributions).

Intuitively,
$$
\hat{\phi}(f) = \int d^4 x f(x) \hat{\phi}(x).
$$

But this formula is only formal, because $\hat{\phi}(x)$ doesn't mathematically exist.

For any two test functions $f_{1,2}$, the quantity

$$
\left< \hat{\phi}(f_1) \hat{\phi}(f_2) \right> = \int d^4 x f_1(x) \int d^4 y f_2(y) \cdot G(x - y)
$$

is finite and well defined, even when $G$ has a divergence on the light cone.